# Merge en Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Cuando uso la función `merge`, la variable que uso para unir los dataframe, así como las demás variables de uno de los dataframe se convierten NA, se pierden. No logro saber por qué ni cómo arreglarlo.

Uso: `merge(dt1,dt2, by="variable1")`

Toda la columna de *"variable1"* sale con NA, así como las otras variables pertenecientes a *dt1*.

Comment: ¿`variable1` existe en los dos `data.frames`? ¿Hay valores coincidentes en las dos tablas? Lamentablemente sin ver los datos es imposible darte una respuesta

Comment: Y de paso: Bienvenida Carolina Chaves a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.